Is there a way to get the images where the Ultralytics YOLOv5 model missed the object?
I am using the version developed by Ultralytics (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) for my application. It is performing well but is, obviously, not correct everytime.
Is there a way to see the cases where this model failed so I can restrategize my data collection and/or annotation techniques?
I tried looking at the runs/ directory that stores the relevant parts from each training run but to no avail.
